# Cursor return only 1 row, after bulkinsert 10 values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I create ContentProvider class and have some troubles with test it.

Here is Tests code :
public void testBulkInsert() {

```
    ContentValues[] bulkInsertContentValues = createBulkInsertVenueValues(VENUE_ID);

    // Register a content observer for our bulk insert.
    TestUtilities.TestContentObserver venueObserver = TestUtilities.getTestContentObserver();
    mContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(FoursquareContract.VenuesEntry.CONTENT_URI, true, venueObserver);

    int insertCount = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(FoursquareContract.VenuesEntry.CONTENT_URI, bulkInsertContentValues);

    venueObserver.waitForNotificationOrFail();
    mContext.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(venueObserver);

    assertEquals(insertCount, BULK_INSERT_RECORDS_TO_INSERT);

    // A cursor is your primary interface to the query results.
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            FoursquareContract.VenuesEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null, // leaving "columns" null just returns all the columns.
            null, // cols for "where" clause
            null, // values for "where" clause
            null  // sort order == by DATE ASCENDING
    );

    // we should have as many records in the database as we've inserted
    assertEquals(cursor.getCount(), BULK_INSERT_RECORDS_TO_INSERT);

    // and let's make sure they match the ones we created
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for ( int i = 0; i < BULK_INSERT_RECORDS_TO_INSERT; i++, cursor.moveToNext() ) {
        TestUtilities.validateCurrentRecord("testBulkInsert.  Error validating VenuesEntry " + i,
                cursor, bulkInsertContentValues[i]);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

(fail with expected:<1> but was:<10>
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50))

Link to content provider: https://github.com/melle095/OneSquare/blob/starting/app/src/main/java/com/a_leonov/onesquare/data/VenueProvider.java

I cant find whats wrong.. Have you any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of "BULK_INSERT_RECORDS_TO_INSERT"? I think that it is 1, but I need a confirmation

Comment: so in `query` method does it switch to `case VENUES:` case?

Comment: @IulianPopescu bulk_insert value is 10. But cursor.getcount return 1. Prev test assertEquals(insertCount, BULK_INSERT_RECORDS_TO_INSERT) succesfull

Comment: @pskink yep. Thats right

Comment: so did you check what that `query` return? call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` on returned value

Comment: @pskink I saw in debugger, that cursor have only 1 row

Comment: the first one, the last one? what `dumpCursor` shows?

Comment: @pskink No, I didnt run dumpCursor yet. I saw one row in the tree of cursor object

Comment: @pskink, I run dumpCursor, Its return last one row.

Comment: I found error. Its UNIQUE field with replace policy in SQL db, so when i fill contentValues, i didn`t change unique value and its replace every time.. Thanks for help!